# How to run Thunderbird filters after getting all messages

Tags: thunderbird

I want to be able to run a specific filter after Thunderbird is done getting messages. All I'm able to do with vanilla TB is to pick the filter runtime before or after Junk classification, but nothing more granular.

What I want to happen is, I press GET ALL MESSAGES. TB retrieves all messages. TB is idle. Filter runs.

Ideally I can set it so it happens at every mail call, even the automatic ones, but I'd be happy if it only happens on manual calls too.